# How to Increase/decrease UIButton width according to title lable text changes?

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout, storyboard, nslayoutconstraint

The Question I have asked is purely using auto-layout, I don't want to setup the frames manually according to text width.

I am aware of the changes **Content hugging priority** and I have used the same for one label and one button it works fine for the label but not for the button, can anyone help

Answer (score 1):

The button already sets its “intrinsic content width” to fit its title.

If no other constraints override that intrinsic content width, the button will be that intrinsic width, which is what you want. Demo:

[image: demo]

Here's my storyboard outline:

[image: storyboard outline]

I set the Alignment of the horizontal stack view to “Left” (instead of “Fill”) so it wouldn't stretch the top row to fill the screen width.

If your button is **not** at its intrinsic width, you have higher-priority (probably priority 1000) constraints forcing it to some other width.

You can try to force it to always stay at its intrinsic content width by setting both its Content Hugging Priority and its Content Compression Resistance Priority to 1000.

If you set both priorities to 1000, and you have any other required constraints that prevent the button from being its intrinsic size, you will get error messages in the debug log at runtime telling you that you have conflicting (unsatisfiable) constraints. These messages will include the full set of constraints, so you can try to track down what constraints you have that you don't want.

Comment: Thanks @rob, I have some question:
What constraints have you given to button? is there any dependency on stack view?

Comment: I didn't put any constraints on the button. The top-level (vertical) stack view has constraints to the superview's top, leading, and trailing edges. The document outline shows every constraint I created.

Comment: what if I don't want to use stack view?

Comment: Then… don't use a stack view. The important parts of my answer have nothing to do with stack views.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this, you can create the custom View: Take - `UIView` and change it's class to `UIButton` and Add the `UILabel` and apply all required constraints.
With this all setup you can achieve the desire UI. 
Please try this If you want to implement like this.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Autolayout constraints]

- `UILabel` object's width constraint should be a Less Than
  or Equal relation
- `UIButton` object's width constraint should be a Greater
  Than or Equal relation
- `UILabel` object's horizontal Content Hugging Priority
  should be 249 (as per my constraint settings shown above)
- And set `UILabel` width constant value as maximum possible value as your requirement.

And related code as:

```
[buttonObject setTitle:@"Button title is ..." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonObject sizeToFit];
```